# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have created a web application in mvc3 and created two partial views
one having controls like dropdownlist.
second having webgrid which shows data from database.

```
partialview1.cshtml
@model Mapping.Models.SecurityIdentifierMapping

@using (Html.BeginForm("Mapping", "Home"))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("SecurityID", Model.PricingSecurityID, "-- Select SecurityID --")
    <br />    
    @Html.DropDownList("CUSIPID", Model.PricingSecurityID, "-- Select CUSIPID --")
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Map</button>
}

partialview2.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<Mapping.Models.SecurityIdentifierMapping>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mapping";
    WebGrid grid = null;
    if (Model.Count() > 0 ){
    grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
                            defaultSort: "Id",
                            canPage: true,
                            canSort: true,
                            rowsPerPage:20);
    }
}


<h2>Mapping</h2>


@if (grid != null)
{
@grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "grid",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                                            grid.Column("", header: null, format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = (int)item.id })  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = (int)item.id })</text>),
                                            grid.Column("PricingSecurityID"),
                                            grid.Column("CUSIP")
                                          )

                )
}
<br />
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
</p>

in index.cshtml


<div>
@Html.Partial("_ControlsPartial",)
</div>

<div>
@Html.Partial("_WebGridPartial")
</div>

HomeController.cs
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SecurityIdentifierMapping objModel = new SecurityIdentifierMapping();
            objModel.PricingSecurityID = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID();
            objModel.CUSIP = objRepository.GetCUSIP();
            return View(objModel);

        }
```

How can i show webgrid and populate dropdown with same Index()??

getting error :(
what should be 2nd parameter inside @Html.Partial() so that both grid and control works fine on same page.?

Comment: Any MVC expert in house plz give me any hint?

Comment: What type is the model of the current page?

Comment: IEnumerable<Mapping.Models.SecurityIdentifierMapping>

Comment: and other problem is how can i used same index method for binding dropdown and to show webgrid ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `SecurityIdentifierMapping` model to the `Index` view. Inside this Index view you are calling 2 partials:

```
@Html.Partial("_ControlsPartial")
```

and:

```
@Html.Partial("_WebGridPartial")
```

The first one works fine because it is strongly typed to `SecurityIdentifierMapping` but the second one (the one with the grid) doesn't work because it is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<SecurityIdentifierMapping>`. Thus the exception you are getting.

I would recommend you using a view model which will contain 2 properties: one simple `SecurityIdentifierMapping` that you could pass to the first partial and an `IEnumerable<SecurityIdentifierMapping>` property that you will pass to the second partial. It is the controller action that will fill this view model and pass it to the Index view:

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div>
    @Html.Partial("_ControlsPartial", Model.SecurityIdentifier)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.Partial("_WebGridPartial", Model.Identifiers)
</div>
```

Comment: 1.what is 'Model.Identifiers'? and 
2.which @model statements should i use on two partial views and inside index.cshtml? 
3.what about Index() method should i keep it as it is?
how can i select then to show webgrid data?

Comment: `Identifiers` is a property on your view model of type `IEnumerable<SecurityIdentifierMapping>`. 2. Inside the partial views you could keep the same @model as you have currently. Inside `Index.cshtml` you could use `@model MyViewModel` as shown in my answer. 3. Since the partial containing the webgrid is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<SecurityIdentifierMapping>` you could use the model directly as datasource to the grid. All that's left is to have your controller action instantiate the view model and populate the 2 properties, i.e. prepare the data necessary by your view.

Comment: inside index.cshtml in Index() method i'm doing View(dbContext.SecurityIdentifierMappings.ToList())
which is giving me error :
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mapping.Models.SecurityIdentifierMapping]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mapping.Models.SecurityIdentifierMappingViewModel]'.

Comment: Yes, I have already covered that part in my answer. You need a view model.